# Kafka Consumer with limited number of retries when processing messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm having a hard time figuring simple patterns for handling exceptions in the consumer of a Kafka topic.
Scenario is as follows: in the consumer I call an external service. If the service is unavailable I want to retry a few times and then stop consuming.

The simplest pattern seems a blocking synchronous way of dealing with it, something like this in java:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    boolean processed=false;
    int count=0;
    while (!processed) {
        try {
            callService(..); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (count++ < 3) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                continue;
            } else throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have the feeling there must be a simpler approach (without using third party libraries), and one that avoids blocking the thread.

Seems like a common thing we would like to have, yet I could not find a simple example for this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such retrial mechanism provided by Kafka out of the box. With the experience of using RabbitMQ where the MQ provides a retry exchange. These exchanges are called as `Dead-Letter-Exchanges` in RabbitMQ.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

You can apply the same pattern in the case of kafka.

On message processing failure we can publish a copy of the message to another topic and wait for the next message. Let’s call the new topic the ‘`retry_topic`’. The consumer of the ‘`retry_topic`’ will receive the message from the Kafka and then will wait some predefined time, for example one hour, before starting the message processing. This way we can postpone next attempts of the message processing without any impact on the ‘main_topic’ consumer. If processing in the ‘retry_topic’ consumer fails we just have to give up and store the message in the ‘failed_topic’ for further manual handling of this problem. The ‘main_topic’ consumer code may look like this:

Pushing message to retry_topic on failure/exception

```
void consumeMainTopicWithPostponedRetry() {
    while (true) {
        Message message = takeNextMessage("main_topic");
        try {
            process(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            publishTo("retry_topic");
            LOGGER.warn("Message processing failure. Will try once again in the future.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer of the retry topic

```
void consumeRetryTopic() {
    while (true) {
        Message message = takeNextMessage("retry_topic");
        try {
            process(message);
            waitSomeLongerTime();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            publishTo("failed_topic");
            LOGGER.warn("Message processing failure. Will skip it.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The above strategy and examples are picked from the below link. The whole credit goes to the owner of the blog post.
https://blog.pragmatists.com/retrying-consumer-architecture-in-the-apache-kafka-939ac4cb851a

For non-blocking way of doing above can be understood by reading the whole blog post. Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution if you want to keep on consuming no matter what. But I would also want the possibility to just stop consuming, e.g. because some backend system is failing and you don't want  to hammer it.

Comment: For the same reason we are going to create multiple topics for not hitting the DB. This solution is going to help you avoid two things 

1. Retrying hitting the DB every time a message fails to persists>
2. Skipping the message by pushing the message to a different queue for later consumption.

Comment: I don't understand. We're continuously processing messages from the main topic. If the backend service (e.g. DB) is failing, then all messages will fail and they will all be moved to the retry_queue. But in the mean time you've hammered the backend. I would have expected some built-in function in kafka to just stop consuming from the main topic after x retries. Sort of a circuit breaker. But perhaps this just does not exist in kafka and we need to build complex logic our selves.

Comment: When a DB is down why do you feel that you are hammering. I think you are complicating things. When a DB is down i.e the host is unavailable. When you try to connect a DB you will get host unavailable so there is not point of connecting to db.

Comment: You might be right though a DB that is down might also be a web service that is overloaded. In that case however I think that I could combine retrying for ever with a circuit breaker for the service call.

Comment: Also this doesn't seem scalable. The retry consumer only takes one message at a time? If you block the consumer for X time (1 hour for example), what happens if 3 messages fail? If the block time is 1 hour then the last message will only be processed in 3 hours?

Comment: this is not a foolproof solution, what if the service dies before publishing to failed_topic?